# How to pass curent param to <Link> in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating multilanguage app.
This is part of my routes.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    {subRoutes}
    <Route path=":lang">
        {subRoutes}
    </Route>
</Route>
```

in App.js i have links.

```
 <Link to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</Link>
 <Link to="about">About</Link>
```

What i need is to pass :lang parameter to Links. When I visit URL example.com/de the "about" link should redirect me to example.com/fr/about. But instead it redirects me to example.com/about.
P.S. i am using react-router 2.0.0

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [React Router official docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors):

> From the upgrade guide from 1.x to 2.x:
>
> `<Link to>`, onEnter, and isActive use location descriptors
>
> `<Link to>` can now take a location descriptor in addition to strings.
>   The query and state props are deprecated.
>
> // v1.0.x
>
> ```
> <Link to="/foo" query={{ the: 'query' }}/>
> ```
>
> // v2.0.0
>
> ```
> <Link to={{ pathname: '/foo', query: { the: 'query' } }}/>
> ```

You can pass in `lang` param as you would expect, inside the `param` object, similar to how query parameters work, if you are using a pre-v2 react-router and a named route.

If `param` object won't work for you, the obvious alternative would be to do something like this:

```
<Link to={`/${this.props.params.lang}/about`} > About </Link>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have already tried that. Its not solution i am looking for. This creates "example.com/about?lang=fr" but i want example.com/fr/about

Comment: That probably means you used the `query` object, which will result in a query parameter. Did you try using the `param` object? As long as the route is set up with the `:lang` param, which in your case is fine, it should work.

Comment: Well i still cannot make it work i am using `<Link to={{pathname: "/about", param: {lang: this.props.params.lang}}}>About</Link>` but it redirects me still to example.com/about

Comment: @palci12 provided you with an alternative. Unfortunately `param` object will work with named routes only and it was removed in v2. Hence my initial question of which version.

Comment: so there is no solution to my problem? Or is there another solution how to switch languages with react-router to be SEO friendly?

Comment: As you can see [here, in the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#to), this would be the only solution currently. SEO related optimizations can be achieved and a site-map can be built with no issues, however for that you would need an isomorphic app with server-side rendering, so that crawlers get a fully rendered page.

Comment: It is isomorphic for diferent language content i am using FLUX but i dont like ?lang=en query for URL

Comment: Could someone provide a example for v4?

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, put link in the component of route :lang.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    {subRoutes}
    <Route path=":lang" **component={LinkComponent}**>
        {subRoutes}
    </Route>
</Route>
```

then in LinkComponent.jsx:

```
<Link to={`/${this.props.route.path}/about`}>About</Link>
```

Comment: I cannot make your link to work it gives me this route `%60/$%7Bthis.props.route.path%7D/about%60`